# How to control node list from node red

Tags: javascript, node-red

I am working on node red and stuck with one problem.

How can we control the list of node (letf panel node) dynamically. Depending upon query string parameter i have to load only specific node on left side. Is there any way.

I can see red.min.js has function "loadNodeCatalogs" and tried to apply some condition, but it is not working.

Thanks
Shrwan

Answer (score 1):

Node-RED does not provide any means to dynamically change the contents of the palette. It displays what the runtime gives it.

If you would like to discuss your requirements in more detail so we can explore what could be done, please use the [discussion forum](https://discourse.nodered.org) as this isn't a discussion suitable for SO.